# Can't connect to other volumes (Dell Equal Logic SAN Headquarters)

Tags: windows-server-2008, raid, iscsi, dell-equallogic

Investigating an older server and disk array (Dell EqualLogic PS4100). The server has Dell EqualLogic SAN Headquarters onit. In Group Manager on the server I can see 5 out of 7 volumes as online/active. I can see the different disk usage stats for the various volumes as well.

When I do an auto-config via ISCSI initiator (Windows 2008 R2), it only mounted 1 of the 5 to the server.

When I do "iscsicli.exe ListTargets" it only shows two entries one related to the volume that mounted and another with "-vss-control".

Where are all the other targets/volumes?

I'm not seeing any obvious differences in the settings between the different volumes in Group Manager that would cause the others not to mount.

Any ideas/suggestions are most welcome. Not super familiar with Dell Equal Logic SAN HQ.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple problems;

> I can see 5 out of 7 volumes as online/active.

Why the other 2 are offline ? Can you show a printscreen, as it can be a simple reason like snapshot space overused and the Equalogic put the volume offline.

> When I do an auto-config via ISCSI initiator (Windows 2008 R2), it
> only mounted 1 of the 5 to the server.

Make sure what are those volumes. Are they should be discovered by that server ? As if it's in example a linux partition you might break the volume by mounting it. The fact it don't mount is probably because in the volume target in SAN HQ your server is not listed as authorized to mount it. PS4100 allow IP restriction and MSCHAP's one for the volume mount.

> When I do "iscsicli.exe ListTargets" it only shows two entries one
> related to the volume that mounted and another with "-vss-control".

This is normal if you are multipathing to the volume.

A note; a PS4100 is really old. I recommend to not use that for production use or to start planning to migrate off it. *I started to use them like 12 years ago, in 2009* if my memory is good.